# Write chemical equation with square arrow?

Tags: arrows, chemfig, chemistry

I asked this question previously but when I used `\polyglossia` package code does not give me the same result, If any one can help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.0]{Simplified Arabic}
\newcommand{\en}{\textenglish}
\newcommand{\ar}{\textarabic}

\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}

\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{CH_3-CH_2-CH_2-CH_2-OH}
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid west)
    {->[ \footnotesize\chemfig{K_2Cr_2O_7}/\chemfig{H^{+}} ]}[,1.6]
    \chemfig{CH_3-CH_2-CH_2-C(=[2]O)
        -@{h3}H}
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid east){0}[-90,2]
    \chemfig{CH_3-CH_2-CH_2-C(=[2]O)-O@{h4}H}
    \schemestop
    \chemmove{
        \draw[shorten <=5pt, shorten >=5pt]
        (h3) -- ([xshift=25pt]h3.center) -- node[pos=0.5,right] {\footnotesize [O]} ([xshift=25pt]h4.center) -- (h4);
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to be cause by the use of the `poyglossia` package, but moe so due to the fact, that you most likely used XeLaTeX to compile the MWE in your question. For a related question, see also: [How to fix chemfig's chemmove in XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321684/134144)

Comment: What about an alternative approach such as `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_3-CH_2-CH_2-CH_2-OH}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west)
{->[ \footnotesize\chemfig{K_2Cr_2O_7}/\chemfig{H^{+}} ]}[,1.6]
\chemfig{CH_3-CH_2-CH_2-C(=[2]O)-@{h3}H}
\arrow(@c2--){->[*{0}{\footnotesize[O]}]}[-90]
\chemfig{CH_3-CH_2-CH_2-C(=[2]O)-O@{h4}H}
\schemestop
\end{document}`. This should also work when compiled using XeLaTeX:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH6lH.png

Comment: Thanks a lot, leandriis.