Using two subschemes in a single compound messes up output
In a simple chemical reaction (A + B → C), I'm trying to draw 2 vertical arrows, one exactly below the letter "A" and one exactly below the letter "B". chemfig's documentation includes an example of how to draw an arrow below the letter "A" using \subscheme:
\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
\schemestart
    \subscheme{A} \+ B \arrow C
    \arrow(@c2--)[-90] E
\schemestop


However, when I try to extend this example using \subscheme{B} (\subscheme{B \arrow[-90] D} messes up spacing, since the actual figure is more complicated) in order to draw an arrow below the letter "B" as well, the output is not what I expected:
\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
\schemestart
    \subscheme{A} \+ \subscheme{B} \arrow C
    \arrow(@c2--)[-90] E
    \arrow(@c3--)[-90] D
\schemestop


Why does this happen? The document is compiled with XeLaTex.

I also don't understand the reason for this problem.
But it is possible to do this scheme without using \subscheme
\documentclass[border=2mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{@{a}A} \+ \chemfig{@{b}B} \arrow C
    \arrow(@{a}--)[-90] \chemfig{E}
    \arrow(@{b}--)[-90] \chemfig{D}
    \schemestop
\end{document}


And no, the arrows will not be below F and G if these are added, they will remain below A and B, where the markers are (@{a} and @{b})
Using your code provided in the comment:
\documentclass[border=2mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{F} \+ \chemfig{G} \arrow \chemfig{@{a}A} \+ \chemfig{@{b}B} \arrow C \arrow(@{a}--)[-90] \chemfig{E} \arrow(@{b}--)[-90] \chemfig{D}
    \schemestop
\end{document}



Won't work if there is text before A + B (e.g. F \+ G \arrow ..: the arrows will be drawn below F and G instead of A and B.

@double-beep   In the scheme I created, the arrows will be drawn below @{a} and @{b}, always.

Yes, but what if there is text before A and B? For example, \chemfig{F} \+ \chemfig{G} \arrow \chemfig{@{a}A} \+ \chemfig{@{b}B} \arrow C \arrow(@{a}--)[-90] \chemfig{E} \arrow(@{b}--)[-90] \chemfig{D} will draw the arrows below F and G.

Using pdftex to compile the document produces the correct output (the one you posted in your answer), but that doesn't happen with xetex (i.e. arrows appear below F and G).

It seems that xetex has problems handling the \arrow command https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321684/how-to-fix-chemfigs-chemmove-in-xetex

It might be better to compile the reaction into a "standalone" document using pdflatex and insert the pdf figure into your xetex document.
